# How do you disable screen rotation using Cocoa-Touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I can't disable screen rotation with:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
     return NO;
   }
```

screen rotation will disable only if I disabled it from the general info of the project
but I don't wont to disable it from there, this is my code (not a lot):

```
#import "MainPage.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
@interface MainPage ()



@end


@implementation MainPage
Reachability *internetReachableFoo;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if(result.height == 480)
        {
            background.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
            about.frame = CGRectMake(20, 401, 280, 44);
        }
    }
    NSUserDefaults *userdetails =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *userid = [userdetails objectForKey:@"userid"];
    NSString *username = [userdetails objectForKey:@"username"];
    if (userid != NULL && username != NULL) {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Home" sender:self];
        NSLog(@"connceted");
    }
    else
    {
        signOutlet.hidden = NO;
        loginOutlet.hidden = NO;
    }

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I am using IOS 8 and IOS 7 any idea ?
*** edit ***

ok, I don't get it in other VC its work and can't rotate
this is my other VC (I don't see any change)

```
#import "About.h"

@interface About ()

@end

@implementation About

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if(result.height == 480)
        {
            background.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
            aboutText.frame = CGRectMake(15, 68, 290, 319);
            home.frame = CGRectMake(67, 414, 187, 38);
        }
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you want to disable rotation for your whole app or just one VC?

Comment: Only from some of my VC.

Comment: You should also implement `- 
supportedInterfaceOrientations`.

Comment: ok, I don't get it in other VC its work and can't rotate, I edited the message with the code of the other VC

Comment: I also implement to `- supportedInterfaceOrientations` and not work yet. `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}`

Comment: how do you present this VC? if you're presenting it modally within uinavigationcontroller, you should override these above mentioned methods in your uinavigationcontroller or any container controller that holds your current VC

Comment: deathhorse, thanks man you right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method in your view controller along with the `shouldAutorotate` method. So lets say you want this one specific view controller limited to only the Portrait orientation, you would have:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //...
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    //...
}


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    // support only portrait landscape
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}


- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    // have autorotate set to YES so the screen can rotate if not in Portrait orientation
    return YES;
}


- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    // not necessary, but this makes the view start in Portrait orientation on the initial load
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

@end
```

Hope this helps